# Как задать анимированную траекторию img картинки?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css-animation

Здраствуйте всем! Искал решение проблемы, но конкретного ответа не нашёл. Везде по кускам собирал информацию и ничего не склеилось.

В общем, вопрос следующий: есть в макете Figma картинка ракеты с нарисованной пунктирной траекторией. Её нужно анимировать так, чтобы img картинка ракеты двигалась по заданной траектории и оставляла за собой пунктирную линию [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на css самое простое что приходит в голову, куча блоков разбросаных по всему макету, с `border-radius: 100500px; border: 3px orange dashed;` (или доттер... вечно путаю типы линий бордеров...) изначально все блоки `display: none` по мере движения ракеты включать блоки. но лучше таки глянь в сторону svg или хотя бы canvas, на css кривые рисовать тот еще геморрой.

Comment: чудоковатый человек но посмотрите как он делает эту анимашку: https://youtu.be/fR0tHI0nFYk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делать как написал puffleeck точно не надо.
Следует анимацию ракеты сделать при помощи библиотеки gsap, как советовал Monkey Mutant. Пунктирный появляющийся путь делается следующим образом: добавляем две картинки SVG, одну линию пунктирную как на вашей картинки, другую точно такую же, но сплошную и белую. Далее помещаем их обе в HTML, но белую поверх пунктирной. Потом по принципу, который описан в ссылке ниже
https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works
анимируем белую, полностью убирая её. Получается так, что изначально она закрывает пунктирную, но затем она "уменьшается", показывая пунктирную. Это создаёт видимость того, будто пунктирная появляется сама.